# Date sequence in R spanning B.C.E. to A.D

Tags: r, date

I would like to generate a sequence of dates from 10,000 B.C.E. to the present.  This is easy for 0 C.E. (or A.D.):

```
ADtoNow <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("0/1/1"), to = Sys.Date(), by = "day")
```

But I am stumped as to how to generate dates before 0 **AD**. Obviously, I could do years before present but it would be nice to be able to graph something as BCE and AD.

Comment: Given `?as.Date` says, "Note: Years before 1CE (aka 1AD) will probably not be handled correctly." I don't think you'll have much luck.

Comment: FYI, medieval monks were bad at math, and made year "1 BC" immediately precede "1 AD", without a year zero inbetween.  So when you read that Julius Caesar was assassinated in 44 BC, they actually mean he was killed in the year -43 in any rational system.  ... Sorry I'm not helping with the actual problem.

Comment: Just so that anyone isn't confused by @criticalfix. That's in the Gregorian calendar system. The astronomical and ISO systems _do_ include a year 0.
The poster of this question never specified which calendar system is being used, so there's only ambiguity to be had in that area. Different calendar libraries handle year 0 in Gregorian differently-be sure to check how yours works to avoid a 1-off error.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Ricardo's suggestion, here is some testing of how things work. Or don't work for that matter.

I will repeat Joshua's warning taken from `?as.Date` for future searchers in big bold letters:

## "Note: Years before 1CE (aka 1AD) will probably not be handled correctly."

```
as.integer(as.Date("0/1/1"))
[1] -719528

as.integer(seq(as.Date("0/1/1"),length=2,by="-10000 years"))
[1]  -719528 -4371953

seq(as.Date(-4371953,origin="1970-01-01"),Sys.Date(),by="1000 years")
# nonsense
 [1] "0000-01-01" "'000-01-01" "(000-01-01" ")000-01-01" "*000-01-01"
 [6] "+000-01-01" ",000-01-01" "-000-01-01" ".000-01-01" "/000-01-01"
[11] "0000-01-01" "1000-01-01" "2000-01-01"

> as.integer(seq(as.Date(-4371953,origin="1970-01-01"),Sys.Date(),by="1000 years"))
# also possibly nonsense
 [1] -4371953 -4006710 -3641468 -3276225 -2910983 -2545740 -2180498 -1815255
 [9] -1450013 -1084770  -719528  -354285    10957
```

Though this does seem to work for graphing somewhat:

```
yrs1000 <- seq(as.Date(-4371953,origin="1970-01-01"),Sys.Date(),by="1000 years")
plot(yrs1000,rep(1,length(yrs1000)),axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
box()
axis(2)
axis(1,at=yrs1000,labels=c(paste(seq(10000,1000,by=-1000),"BC",sep=""),"0AD","1000AD","2000AD"))
title(xlab="Year",ylab="Value")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quite some time has gone by since this question was asked. With that time came a new R package, [gregorian](https://github.com/edgararuiz/gregorian) which can handle BCE time values in the `as_gregorian` method.

Here's an example of piecewise constructing a list of dates that range from -10000 BCE to the current year.

```
library(lubridate)
library(gregorian)

# Container for the dates
dates <- c()
starting_year <- year(now())
# Add the CE dates to the list
for (year in starting_year:0){
  date <- sprintf("%s-%s-%s", year, "1", "1")
  dates <- c(dates, gregorian::as_gregorian(date))
}

starting_year <- "-10000"
# Add the BCE dates to the list
for (year in starting_year:0){
start_date <- gregorian::as_gregorian("-10000-1-1")
date <- sprintf("%s-%s-%s", year, "1", "1")
dates <- c(dates, gregorian::as_gregorian(date))
}
```

How you *use* the list is up to you, just know that the relevant properties of the date objects are `year` and `bce`. For example, you can loop over list of dates, parse the year, and determine if it's BCE or not.

```
> gregorian_date <- gregorian::as_gregorian("-10000-1-1")
> gregorian_date$bce
[1] TRUE
> gregorian_date$year
[1] 10001
```

#### Notes on 0AD

The gregorian package assumes that when you mean Year 0, you're really talking about year 1 (shown below). I personally think an exception should be thrown, but that's the mapping users needs to keep in mind.

```
> gregorian::as_gregorian("0-1-1")
[1] "Monday January 1, 1 CE"
```

This is *also* the case with BCE

```
> gregorian::as_gregorian("-0-1-1")
[1] "Saturday January 1, 1 BCE"
```

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

As @JoshuaUlrich commented, the short answer is no.

However, you can splice out the year into a separate column and then convert to integer.  Would this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The package `lubridate` seems to handle "negative" years ok, although it does create a year `0`, which from the above comments seems to be inaccurate.  Try:

```
library(lubridate)

start <- -10000

stop <- 2013

myrange <- NULL

for (x in start:stop) {

     myrange <- c(myrange,ymd(paste0(x,'-01-01')))
}
```

Comment: Not knowing `lubridate`, I can only guess it still uses the internal R `Date` objects at some stage. Josh's warning probably still holds true in that case.