# How to make B.C. Date format in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have string like `1/1/-2150`. How to make `Date` format from that in R

`lubridate` back:

```
library(lubridate)
dmy("1/1/-2150")
[1] "2150-01-01"

as.Date("1/1/-2150",format="%d/%m/%Y")
[1] NA
```

Now `1/1/-2150` have class character. 
I need same value but with class `Date`
Thanks

**UPDATE** 
Something like that, but using `lubridate` if it possible

```
minus=as.numeric(dmy("1/1/-2150"))
x<-as.numeric(ymd("0000-1-1"))
dt=as.Date(x*2-minus,origin="1970-01-01")+days(1) 
str(dt)
Date[1:1], format: "-2150-01-01"
```

Comment: What is the expected output? BC means Before Chirst?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966957/date-sequence-in-r-spanning-b-c-e-to-a-d

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, Before Christ. I saw that answer

Comment: So what is the expected output?

Comment: @zx8754 updated

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there aren't any really large R packages tackling this issue ([maybe no one has asked](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/2)). The [gregorian](https://github.com/edgararuiz/gregorian) package should however, be able to tackle your BCE needs.

> gregorian::as_gregorian("-2150-1-1")
> [1] "Tuesday January 1, 2151 BCE"

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but here is a possible solution here. Find how far 2150-01-01 is from 0000-01-01 and then make it a negative number and pass it to `as.Date()` with the origin '0000-01-01'

```
y <- as.numeric(as.Date("2150-01-01"))+ as.numeric(as.Date("1970-01-01") - as.Date("0000-01-01"))
y
#785272

x <- as.Date(-y, "0000-01-01")
x
#"-2151-12-31"
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify the `-` in the `format`

```
as.Date("1/1/-2150",format="%d/%m/-%Y")
#[1] "2150-01-01"
```

Comment: This will make the date in the future, OP is in the past BC = before christ?

Comment: @zx8754  As I understand the question, the OP gets NA for as.Date and date with `dmy`

Comment: Yes, it does give date class, not sure if this is what OP needs. Imagine if OP has `c("1/1/-2150", "1/2/1950")`

Comment: @zx8754  Then, it will be done in two steps `out <- as.Date(v1,format="%d/%m/-%Y");
out[is.na(out)] <- as.Date(v1[is.na(out)], format = "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: Then how would we know which one is BC and which one is AD?

Comment: @zx8754  Perhaps another column as identifier where there is `-` and not `-`  i.e. `c("AD", "BC")[grepl("-", v1) + 1]`