# Is it possible to make a date with negative year?

Tags: r, date

I have this data I wanted to convert to dates, but I doubt it is possible with year that is below 0, below is the snippets

```
library(datasets)
library(quantmod)
data(treering)
tree_df = data.frame(ds=index(treering), y=as.numeric(treering))
> head(tree_df)
     ds     y
1 -6000 1.345
2 -5999 1.077
3 -5998 1.545
4 -5997 1.319
5 -5996 1.413
6 -5995 1.069
> tail(tree_df)
       ds     y
7975 1974 1.031
7976 1975 1.027
7977 1976 1.173
7978 1977 1.471
7979 1978 1.444
7980 1979 1.160

?treering
    Yearly Treering Data, -6000–1979
    Description
    Contains normalized tree-ring widths in dimensionless units.

    Usage
    treering
    Format
    A univariate time series with 7981 observations. The object is of class "ts".

    Each tree ring corresponds to one year.
```

Is there a way to convert the data into dates with a negative year in its own way? like for example "-6000-01-01"?

Comment: `as.Date("-6000-01-01")` returns an error. So I guess it is not possible to have such dates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966957/date-sequence-in-r-spanning-b-c-e-to-a-d

Comment: wow that reference hit the spot @G. Grothendieck, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently by converting Minus Integer to Date help the trick, in this case (-2910983) from the year 1970 is -6000, therefore a sequence of 1 Year will help and then finally converted to Date

```
sequences = seq(as.Date(-2910983,origin="1970-01-01"),as.Date(paste0(max(index(treering)),"-01-01")),by="1 years")
tail(sequences)
[1] "1974-01-01" "1975-01-01" "1976-01-01" "1977-01-01" "1978-01-01" "1979-01-01"
head(sequences)
[1] "-6000-01-01" "-5999-01-01" "-5998-01-01" "-5997-01-01" "-5996-01-01" "-5995-01-01"
```