# R - How should I format a B.C.E. date in timevis?

Tags: r, date, format, timeline

I need to show a series of events in a timeline. Some of this events are before common era. I'm using `timevis` in `R`.

So far, I've tried the following code:

```
library("timevis")
d <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date("0001/01/01"))
d$year <- d$year -1
dates <- (as.Date(d))
names <- c("Test")

dt <- data.frame(start=dates,content=names)
print(dt)

timevis(dt, width = 900)
```

The above code shows an event in the beginning of the year 0 in `timevis`, which is wierd but is not a problem right now. the problem shows up as soon as I change to:

```
d$year <- d$year -2
```

The event jumps in the timeline to 01/01/2001

I just started yesterday with `R` for a personal research project, and I've never worked with BCE dates in any other language before. I've tried `lubridate`.

I've considered this question [Date sequence in R spanning B.C.E. to A.D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966957/date-sequence-in-r-spanning-b-c-e-to-a-d), but I'm asking if there's any `timevis` workaround, maybe. Because this timeline shows BCE years.

**What's the proper way to format a BCE date?**

I am looking forward to a bit of help - Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [discussion](https://github.com/daattali/timevis/issues/99) on github recently about this topic. Using the information from there, you need the following to make it work on RStudio and in an app:

- format the dates as strings
- for BCE dates, you need a minus as prefix and in total 6 digits for the year: `"-002000-01-01"`
- for CE dates, you need in total 4 digits for the year: `"0010-01-01"`

Example code that works for me in RStudio:

```
library(timevis)

dt <- data.frame(content = c("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"),
                 start = c("-000002-01-01", "-000001-01-01",
                                     "0010-01-01", "0100-01-01"))

timevis(dt, width = 900)
```

Comment: I didn't search in the github repo, even tho I searched in the timevis documentation and tried the online demo. They should publish this solution or make it a section in their documentation.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit hidden, I think the original poster there wanted to include it into the documentation but didn't do it. Maybe you can contribute to the issue on github.